# Mock method return value inside a method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

So I have method that validates user

```
public Boolean ValidateUser(username){

    return ValidationHelper(username)

}
```

How do I mock the return value of ValidationHelper? I tried something like following

```
Helper.Setup(item => item.ValidateUser(It.IsAny<String>())).Returns(true);
```

But I got the error:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x=> x.ValidateUser(It.IsAny<string>())
Non-overridable members (here: UserValidation.ValidateUser) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

Comment: How are you mocking `Helper`?

Comment: you shouldn't mock your system under test, but it's dependencies. `ValidationHelper` however is not a dependency, but part of your SuT. You *can* do it, if the `ValidationHelper` was `virtual`, but if that's a good idea is another story.

Comment: @anastaciu I wasn't sure if I can or can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not mocking ValidationHelper, but the ValidateUser method. You can only mock interfaces or virtual members. In your case, you can change the definition to

```cs
public virtual Boolean ValidateUser(username) {...}
```

I don't know whether that's the best option in your case though, because you don't show the call site or the test.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if I can mock the helper function. You just confirmed this for me.